# Create an associative array from simple array

Tags: php, arrays

any recommendation what's the quickest and nicest way to change this array in PHP5:

```
Array (
    [0] => fruit
    [1] => apple
    [2] => vegetable
    [3] => corn
    ... etc
)
```

To this associative array?

```
Array (
    [fruit] => apple
    [vegetable] => corn
    ... etc
)
```

Theoratically I'd need to set each even items as keys and every odd items as the values.

Thanks!

Comment: and what would you do if you got an odd number of elements ?

Comment: There're some problems that don't need heavy use of native language function use and this is one of them: http://3v4l.org/ta9gE

Comment: @alfasin The array is only a 2 field CSV, and have some evaluations to make sure its correct format and have both fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the array, incrementing the counter by 2, and then create the new array.

```
$newArray = array();

$len = count($oldArray);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i+=2){
    $key = $oldArray[$i];
    $val = $i+1 < $len ? $oldArray[$i+1] : '';

    $newArray[$key] = $val;
}
```

Comment: this will give a notice when given array length is not even.

Comment: @developerCK: I know, I was assuming his data was in the "correct" format.

Comment: but this might help isset($oldArray[$i+1])?$oldArray[$i+1]:'';

Comment: @developerCK This would get executed on each iteration, checking the array before seems to be a little bit faster for huge arrays: `/* remove last item from odd arrays */ if( count( $input ) % 2 != 0 ) { array_pop( $input ); }`

Comment: what will happen if he do not want to pop that ?

Comment: @developerCK: That's up to him.  He could pop it, then add it back at the end.

Comment: yes , but while we answering , we should not alter one's input, and result should be according to one's input, not according to ourself

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the input array and increment the counter on each iteration by two:

```
$input = array(
    0 => 'fruit',
    1 => 'apple',
    2 => 'vegetable',
    3 => 'corn',
);

/* remove last item from odd arrays */
if( count( $input ) % 2 != 0 )
{
    array_pop( $input );
}

$output = array();
$inputLength = count( $input );

for( $i = 0; $i < $inputLength; $i = $i + 2 )
{
    $output[$input[$i]] = $input[$i + 1];
}

var_dump( $output );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the joy of playing around...

```
<?php

$arr = array('fruit', 'apple', 'vegetable', 'corn');

$i = $j = 0;
$newArr = array_combine(
    array_filter($arr, function()use(&$i){ return ++$i%2; }),
    array_filter($arr, function()use(&$j){ return $j++%2; })
);
unset($i, $j, $arr);

print_r($newArr);
```

[<kbd>working example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/aba1pV)